# CakePHP-2.4 : subcategories according to categories by ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to get subcategories according to categories by ajax.So I have sent data in controller by ajax get method like bellow code in add.ctp

```
$('document').ready(function(){
            $( "#division" ).change(function() {

                        var value=$('#division').val(); 

                            $.get("<?php echo   Router::url(array('controller'=>'userStoreSelections','action'=>'add'));?>",{list:value},function(data){
                    $('.districts').html(data);
                    alert(data);
                });
            });
    });
```

In controller in find methods when I am writing bellow code It's working fine.

```
$madDistricts = $this->UserStoreSelection->MadDistricts->find('list',array(
            'conditions'=>array('mad_divisions_id'=>3)
));
```

But when I give the value that I have sent by ajax it's not working.I have written like this

```
$madDistricts = $this->UserStoreSelection->MadDistricts->find('list',array(
            'conditions'=>array('mad_divisions_id'=>"$list")
));
```

It showing the query like this

```
SELECT `MadDistricts`.`id`, `MadDistricts`.`name` FROM `store`.`mad_districts` AS `MadDistricts` WHERE `mad_divisions_id` IS NULL
```

After select categories nothing change in query.I have tested ajax code there is no problem to send value.

For more specific this is the add action code

```
public function add() {

        if(isset($this->request->query['list'])){
            $search = $this->request->query['list'];
            echo $search;
        }
        else{
            $search = '';
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->UserStoreSelection->create();
            if ($this->UserStoreSelection->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user store selection has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user store selection could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $madDivisions = $this->UserStoreSelection->MadDivisions->find('list');

            $madDistricts = $this->UserStoreSelection->MadDistricts->find('list',array(
            'conditions'=>array('mad_divisions_id'=>"$list")
         ));
        $madAreas = $this->UserStoreSelection->MadAreas->find('list');
        $users = $this->UserStoreSelection->Users->find('list',array('fields' => array('id','username')));
        $madStores = $this->UserStoreSelection->MadStores->find('list',array('fields' => array('id','store_name')));
        $this->set(compact('madDivisions', 'madDistricts', 'madAreas', 'users','madStores'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your add.ctp file code like as :

```
$('document').ready(function () {
$("#division").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(' / ',true);?>userStoreSelections/subcategories',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'category=' + id,
        success: function (res) {
            var html = '<option>Sub Category</option>';
            if (res.flage == true) {
                 html = res.data;
            }
            $('.districts').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Than create a function in your userStoreSelections for get sub categories as

```
public function subcategories() {

    $response = array('flage' => false);

    $madDistricts = $this->UserStoreSelection->MadDistricts->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array('mad_divisions_id' => $this->request->data['category'])
    ));

    $options = "<option>Subcategories</option>";
    if ($states) {
        $response['flage'] = true;
        foreach ($madDistricts as $id => $name) {
            $options .= "<option value='" . $id . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
        }
        $response['data'] = $options;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: But what is the problem in my code ? I have used just jquery ajax in here.

Comment: Please post your complete function so that i can find what is the problem.

Comment: $madDistricts = $this->UserStoreSelection->MadDistricts->find('list',array(
            'conditions'=>array('mad_divisions_id'=>"$list")
));

How you get the "$list" here ?

Comment: Yes. I have sent list from add.ctp by ajax.

Comment: It didn't received directly in controller.You need to check it in $this->data or $this->params in controller.

Comment: I have checked it.It's printing the value, but not updating query.

Comment: I thing you get the list as  $search = $this->request->query['list'];
than use $search instead of $list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64292/discussion-between-alimon-karim-and-prakash-saini).